# Spring Boot read properties without prefix to a map

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configurationproperties

I need to read all properties in application.properties file in a map 
In the code below the property test has the respective value but the map is empty. How can I fill "map" with the values in the application.properties file without adding a prefix to the properties.

This is my application.properties file

```
AAPL=25
GDDY=65
test=22
```

I'm using @ConfigurationProperties like this

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class InitialConfiguration {
    private HashMap<String, BigInteger> map = new HashMap<>();
    private String test;

    public HashMap<String, BigInteger> getMap() {
        return map;
    }

    public void setMap(HashMap<String, BigInteger> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

    public String getTest() {
        return test;
    }

    public void setTest(String test) {
        this.test = test;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be achieved using the **PropertiesLoaderUtils** and **@PostConstruct**

Please check the sample below:

```
@Configuration
public class HelloConfiguration {
    private Map<String, String> valueMap = new HashMap<>();
    @PostConstruct
    public void doInit() throws IOException {
        Properties properties = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadAllProperties("application.properties");
        properties.keySet().forEach(key -> {
            valueMap.put((String) key, properties.getProperty((String) key));
        });
        System.err.println("valueMap -> "+valueMap);
    }
    public Map<String, String> getValueMap() {
        return valueMap;
    }
    public void setValueMap(Map<String, String> valueMap) {
        this.valueMap = valueMap;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't do it with `@ConfigurationProperties` as far as I'm aware, those require a prefix to be able to load those properties within the bean.

However, if your goal is to obtain "value Y" for "property X" programmatically, you can always inject [`Environment`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html) and use the `getProperty()` method to find certain property, for example:

```java
@Configuration
public class InitialConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @PostConstruct
    public void test() {
        Integer aapl = environment.getProperty("AAPL", Integer.class); // 25
        Integer gddy = environment.getProperty("GDDY", Integer.class); // 65
        Integer test = environment.getProperty("test", Integer.class); // 22
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I tried this but din't want to use the Enviroment directly, but this is the simplest solution

Comment: This should be the selected answer. Loading through environment is the most robust way.

Comment: PropertiesLoaderUtils will load properties in build time. If we change the properties at a later time and re-run the JAR, PropertiesLoaderUtils will not reflect the new changes. In that regards Environment is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

In spring boot, if you need to get a single value from the application.proprties, you just need to use the @Value annotation with the given name

So to get AAPL value just add a class level property like this

```
@Value("${AAPL}")
private String aapl;
```

And if you need to load a full properties file as a map, I'm using the ResourceLoader to load the full file as a stream and then parse it as follows

```
@Autowired
public loadResources(ResourceLoader resourceLoader) throws Exception {      
      Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:myProperties.properties"));
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resource.getInputStream()));
      String line;
      int pos = 0;
      Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
           pos = line.indexOf("=");
           map.put(line.substring(0, pos), line.substring( pos + 1));
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed you can use `@ConfigurationProperties` without prefix to get entire properties known to Spring application i.e. application, system and environment properties etc.

Following example creates a fully populated map as a Spring bean. Then wire / inject this bean wherever you need it.

```
@Configuration
class YetAnotherConfiguration {

    @ConfigurationProperties /* or @ConfigurationProperties("") */
    @Bean
    Map<String, String> allProperties() {
        return new LinkedHashMap<>();
    }

}

@Autowire
void test(Map<String, String> allProperties) {
    System.out.println(allProperties.get("AAPL")); // 25
    ...
}
```

Comment: Newer versions of Spring Boot now require that the `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "non-empty")` annotation has a mandatory `prefix` parameter.

Comment: Indeed IntelliJ complains with "Prefix must be specified" or "Prefix must be non-empty" but there is no restriction mentioned in documentation of [ConfigurationProperties](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.6.7/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationProperties.java). I looks like an inspection bug there. - [IDEA-219436](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-219436)

Answer (score 0):

```
@PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")
public class GlobalConfig {

  public static String AAPL;
  @Value("${AAPL}")
  private void setDatabaseUrl(String value) {
    AAPL = value;
  }
}
```

You have to use @Value to get value from application.properties file

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP question, which wanted to dynamically get a list of all properties.